# OpenWRT set Policy-based routing with multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, openwrt, lede

I have an OpenWRT router. On it, I had set up a couple VPN interfaces. I have a tinc VPN that links all my remote networks together; an OpenVPN tunnel to an overseas location.

Currently, I already have a static routing table that allows me to access my remote networks. For example, my local network `192.168.1.0/24` can access one of my remote networks, which has a local IP range `192.168.0.0/24`, and vice versa. So my hosts on `192.168.1.0/24` can see and access any hosts on `192.168.0.0/24` as though they are on the same switch. There are possibilities that more remote networks may be added to the mesh, but I had set up tinc scripts to handle that case.

```
Kernel IP routing table on my local network
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         111.222.333.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1.2
10.10.0.5       *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
111.222.333.0   *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth1.2
111.222.333.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1.2
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tinc
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```

Now, I have a server on my local network, say `192.168.1.101`, which need to be accessible to all the hosts on the tinc mesh (which is what it's currently doing - great!), and vice versa. However, now I would like *any* other traffic in and out of the server *outside* of the tinc mesh IP ranges to go over the OpenVPN interface. For example, server backs up to `192.168.0.5` at periodic intervals; this is will go over tinc interface. The server can request and download updates from the Internet but that will go through OpenVPN interface (tun0).

I have been trying to look for answers in regards to this issue. Part of the problem is that I only want this server to behave this way. Other hosts on my network can continue to access the Internet through the normal WAN interface (eth1.2).

I hope I'm succinct in my description. My network knowledge is rather limited. I appreciate any tutorial or advice on how to achieve this, or if it is even possible?